# Ms SQL избавиться от дупликатов при left outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть запрос вида

```
update table1 set col1 = case 
                         when table2.valcol = 0 then 'false'
                         when table2.valcol is null  then 'null'
                         else 'true' end
from table1 
left outer join table2 
on table1.id= table2.somecol

table1
id
1
2
3
4

table2
somecol ordercol valcol
1       1        0
1       2        1
1       4        0
2       1        1
2       2        0
```

В итоге если селектить выходит что-то типа

```
somecol ordercol valcol
1       1        0
1       2        1
1       4        0
2       1        1
2       2        0
3       null     null
4       null     null
```

Проблема в том, что появляются дубликаты, пусть это и правильно, но апдейт должен происходить учитывая только последнюю строчку, если отсортировать по ordercol. То есть, мой зарос в итоге неправильно заапдейтит table1, ткк при left outer join появились не отсортированные дубликаты и может учитываться в set col1 = case любое значение из этих дубликатов.

Как подправить запрос (или переписать), чтобы при апдейте учитывалось только последнее значение отсортированное по возрастанию ordercol? Так же, table2 довольно большая таблица и могут возникнуть проблемы со скоростью.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update table1 set col1 = case 
                         when table2top.valcol = 0 then 'false'
                         when table2top.valcol is null  then 'null'
                         else 'true' end
from table1 
outer apply (
    select top 1 * 
    from table2 
    where table1.id= table2.somecol 
    order by ordercol desc
    ) as table2top
```

Скорость выполнения будет зависеть скорее от объема Table1, а не от объема Table2. Ну и от наличия индексов и актуальности статистики - в любом случае при проблемах с производительностью стоит сначала смотреть план, а потом уже править sql.

Comment: Вроде бы оно. Спасибо. Скорость уменьшилась с 30с до 34с. Но это пока не критично.

Comment: 30 секунд это много. Проверяйте план - у вас явно где-то table spool или index scan. Или посмотрите вариант от msi. Он позволит SQL Server сделать hash/merge join, что может быть эффективнее (хотя все равно стоит сначала план посмотреть)

Comment: 63% уходит на Index Seek, но это норм, там сложный where  вида r.col1= ww.col1
and 1000000000 + cast(pgp.col2 as bigint) = ww.col2. Как раз для этой жирной таблицы.

Comment: @sss надо смотреть на number of executions для seek. если большой, и если вызывается в nested loops (грубо говоря в foreach для каждой обновляемой строки) - то пробуйте вариант от msi.

Answer (score 1):

Соединяйте не с таблицей Table 2, а с запросом:

```
select * from Table2 T
join 
(select somecol, max(ordercol) ordercol from Table2 group by somecol) X
on T.somecol=X.somecol and T.ordercol=X.ordercol
```

Да, и левое соединение тут не при чем. При внутреннем была бы та же проблема.